# A user created by curl in Elasticsearch has roles "manage","all","monitor". But when Kibana starts, it doesn't see those and stops its initialization

Tags: authentication, elasticsearch, curl, kibana

I'm trying to start a fresh install of *Kibana* `8.9`.
Currently it isn't ready. "*Kibana server is not ready yet.*" is in front of me.

Elastic `8.9` and the ELK suite look willing to start only if they have some authentication set (it seems that you can't, like in `7.x`, start in a local/dev computer with no security at all).
But you can't parametrize `/etc/systemd/kibana.yaml` with the super account `elastic` to join *Elastic*: it is forbidden.

So I've created a `kib` user that way:

```bash
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/_security/user/kib" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{  "password" : "kibananas",  "enabled": true,  "roles" : [ "manage", "all", "monitor" ],  "full_name" : "Kibana default user",  "email" : "t@dummy.com",  "metadata" : {    "intelligence" : 1  }}' -u elastic:Ox-JoQT0po=pdOT-LeE*
```

and it looks being recognized:

```bash
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/_security/user/kib" -H 'Content-Type: application/json'  -u elastic:Ox-JoQT0po=pdOT-LeE*
{"kib":{"username":"kib","roles":["manage","all","monitor"],"full_name":"Kibana default user","email":"t@dummy.com","metadata":{"intelligence":1},"enabled":true}}
```

But at the time I'm restarting *Kibana*, it fails. Not seeing any roles accompanying this user, while they are set, according to the GET `curl`.

```json
{"service":{"node":{"roles":["background_tasks","ui"]}},"ecs":{"version":"8.6.1"},"@timestamp":"2023-08-23T06:06:59.939+02:00","message":
"Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes. security_exception\n\tRoot causes:\n\t\tsecurity_exception: action [cluster:monitor/nodes/info] is unauthorized for user [kib] with effective roles [] (assigned roles [all,manage,monitor] were not found), this action is granted by the cluster privileges [monitor,manage,all]",
"log":{"level":"ERROR","logger":"elasticsearch-service"},"process":{"pid":54671},"trace":{"id":"6d2deccf2cf5c9d25c253a8a7c4b63d3"},"transaction":{"id":"326083a16bcad34e"}}
```

Therefore, it's initialization is stopped.